# Puppet Rspec: class has not been evaluated

Tags: rspec-puppet

I am writing an rspec test for a puppet module which makes the following call:

```
lookupvar('services::service')
```

When I run the test I get the following warning:
`Could not look up qualified variable 'services::service'; class services has not been evaluated`

I can work around the problem by including *services* module in my init.pp. However, is there a way to require *services* module from my test, e.g. spec_helper.rb or the test case itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding `include ::services` to spec/fixtures/manifests/site.pp